# Sorting an array by looking at another array in python (deep learning purpose)

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, deep-learning

I am actually doing deep learning on white spots images. Thanks to my model I predict a list of points with [x, y] coordinates. I have also a list of the target points with [x', y'] coordinates.
My goal is to compute the euclidean distance between the predicted and the target coordinates.
The length of the list of my predictions is smaller than the list of the targets.

Predictions

```
[[11, 25], [13, 82], [27, 42], [32, 107], [37, 72], [38, 120], [40, 29], [55, 89], [62, 12], [80, 20], [83, 67], [ 86, 108], [94, 23], [107, 56], [108,  38], [111,  89], [115, 36], [116, 52], [116, 121], [119, 57]]
```

Targets

```
[[11, 25], [13, 82], [27, 42], [32, 107], [37, 72], [38, 120], [40, 29], [55, 89], [56, 124], [61, 122], [62, 12], [ 81, 120], [83, 67], [86, 108], [89, 124], [92, 1], [94, 23], [107,  56], [107, 39], [111, 89], [115, 36], [116, 120], [117, 51], [118, 56]]
```

What I want is to sort the arrays of Targets by having their predictions at the same position in the target list of coordinates and hence, having the non-predicted coordinates at the end of the target list.

I have already tried to compute the euclidean distance for each element of the targets by looking at the predictions and taking the lower distance under a threshold to sort the array. The problem I have is that when you have 2 predicted points close to each other and 2 target points related to that prediction, and one of the predicted points is closer to both of the targets than the other prediction, my code does not work.

```
# Align predictions targets in increasing order for the x parameter, the targets not predicted will be at the end of the target list
def align_by_dist(a_sorted, b_sorted):
    for i in range(len(b_sorted)):
        D = []
        for j in range(len(a_sorted)):
            dist = distance.euclidean(a_sorted[j], b_sorted[i])
            if dist < 7: # Select a treshold for the euclidean distance
                D.append(dist) # Append the euclidean distance which is lower than the treshold
                if dist == min(D): # Check if it is the lower euclidean distance between the close micro-bubb
                    b_sorted[j], b_sorted[i] = b_sorted[i], b_sorted[j]
                    # If it is the lowest euclidean distance, put at the same level the target micro-bubble
                    # and its closest predicted micro-bubble                 
    return a_sorted, b_sorted
```

*a_sorted is the list of predictions and b_sorted is the list of targets.*

Here I know that my code only returned a vector with the targets that have a prediction but it is the first step.

The code work in general but here I gave an example where it is not working. The point at [116, 52] is the predictions of the target at [117, 51] but my output is:

```
[[11, 25], [13, 82], [27, 42], [32, 107], [37, 72], [38, 120], [40, 29], [55, 89], [62, 12], [81, 120], [83, 67], [86, 108], [94, 23], [107, 56], [107, 39], [111, 89], [115, 36], [118, 56], [116, 120], [92, 1], [56, 124], [89, 124], [61, 122], [117, 51]]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I may have succeeded with this modification of my code:

```
def align_by_dist(A, B):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        D = [] # This list will contain the index where the euclidean distance is lower than the threshold
        for j in range(len(B)):
            dist = distance.euclidean(A[i], B[j]) # Compute the euclidean distance between a target at index j and a prediction at index I
            if dist <= 4: # Select a treshold for the euclidean distance
                D.append(np.array([dist,j,i])) # Append the euclidean distance and the index of the target and prediction vector
        if D: # If we find an euclidean distance lower than the threshold we can now sort for the index i the list of prediction
            D_sorted = sorted(D,key=lambda elem:elem[0]) # We sort the array of distance lower than the threshold to get the minimum distance for the index I 
            value = D_sorted[0]
            B[value[2].astype(np.int64)], B[value[1].astype(np.int64)] = B[value[1].astype(np.int64)], B[value[2].astype(np.int64)] # We updated the target list position 
            A[value[2].astype(np.int64)] = [1000000,1000000] # We set the value of the predictions very high to not have duplicates when sorting the targets coordinates 
return B
```